# MassTransit Subscriptions and Receiving Own Messages

Tags: msmq, esb, masstransit

I am trying to implement a proof of concept service bus using MassTransit.  I have three applications which need to communicate changes of a common entity type between each other.  So when the user updates the entity in one application, the other two are notified.

Each application is configured as follows with their own queue:

```
bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
    {
        sbc.UseMsmq();
        sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
        sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/app1_queue");
        sbc.UseSubscriptionService("msmq://localhost/subscription");
        sbc.UseControlBus();

        sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
        {
            subs.Handler<IMessage1>(IMessage1_Received);
        });
    });
```

There is also a subscription service application configured as follows:

```
subscriptionBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
    {
        sbc.UseMsmq();
        sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
        sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/subscription");
    });

var subscriptionSagas = new InMemorySagaRepository<SubscriptionSaga>();
var subscriptionClientSagas = new InMemorySagaRepository<SubscriptionClientSaga>();
subscriptionService = new SubscriptionService(subscriptionBus, subscriptionSagas, subscriptionClientSagas);

subscriptionService.Start();
```

The problem is that when one of the applications publishes a message, all three applications receive it (including the original sender).

Is there any way to avoid this (without resorting to adding the application name to the message)?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So MassTransit is a pub/sub system. If you publish a message, everyone registered to receive it will. If you need only some endpoints to receive it, then you really need to directly send. It's just how this works.

You could include the source in your message and discard messages that aren't of interest to you. If you implement the `Consumes.Accept` interface, I think the `Accept` method would allow you to do so easily without mixing that into the normal consumption code.

Comment: To send directly: Instead of calling .Publish() on the bus, obtain (using IEndpointFactory) the endpoint you want to send it to and call .Send() on it.

Comment: Thanks, I was already filtering the messages based on the message source but the Consumes<T>.Selected.Accept filter is a useful tip!

Comment: I made my consumer class implement Consumes<T>.Selected and implemented the Accept method, however the method is never invoked. The consumer consumes all messages.  Did I miss sth?

Comment: Does it implement any other interfaces? I think you have to remove the Consumes<T>.All interface.

Comment: No, just: public class Consumer: Consumes<IMessage1>.Selected

Comment: That should be right, I'd bring a sample up to the mailing list - you'll likely get faster responses than me checking here once in a while: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss